# How to find $F(x) = \int_x^{x^2} (2+\sqrt t )\, dt$ ?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have this problem:

$$
F(x) = \int_x^{x^2} (2+\sqrt t )\, dt
$$

I have to solve the integral.

I got $2x^2+\frac{2x^3}{3}-2x-\frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}$

However, I don't think that it correct.

Comment: Why do you think it's not correct?

Comment: I plugged in a value and did it on the calculator and I get 2 different answers.

Comment: Write the intermediate passages

Comment: i just solved it again @user1763899 , and your result is correct!

Comment: Really? Then I must have typed in something wrong in the calculator. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct:

$$F(x) = \int_x^{x^2} (2+\sqrt t )\, dt = \left[2t + \frac{2t^{3/2}}{3}\right]_{x}^{x^2}
= 2x^2 + \frac{2x^3}{3} - 2x - \frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}$$

My guess is that you inputted it incorrectly into your calculator.